# check checkbox based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to auto check certain boxes based on the value from a dropdown selection. I have been searching forever and I can only seem to find ways to SHOW OR HIDE checkboxes based on dropdown but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: did you try something? it's not that difficult.

Comment: You are going to have to explain your question better. It's tagged both PHP and JavaScript, so which is it? Are you wanting a dropdown to change the values of checkboxes on the same page with JavaScript or are you wanting to change the value of checkboxes on a new page after submitting a form. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried many different things and all of them either don't work or HIDE the checkbox all together.

Comment: @Chris I am wanting the checkboxes to get check VIA javascript right when the dropdown selection changes.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show us?

Comment: @zack.lore I got mad and deleted it... I will re-write something and show. I think its because all my checkboxes have a different "name=" field.. But they have to with what I'm doing. uhhg so confused. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with jQuery.  This code listens for a change event from a dropdown with `id="dropdown"` and checks the checkbox with `id="checkbox"` if the dropdown text was equal to 'foo'.

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
  if($('#dropdown :selected').text() === 'foo') $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

If you want to uncheck the box when the selection is changed again something like this might be better:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
  var text = $('#dropdown :selected').text();
  $('#checkbox').prop('checked', text === 'foo');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro49au2z/1/)

Comment: Problem with that is, if I have 5 checkboxes.... and 3 drop down values... When dropdown 1 is select checkbox 1, 3, 5... If dropdown 2 is select checkboxes 2,3,5 and so on...

Comment: Can I make $('#checkbox', '#checkbox2').prop('checked', true); Basically can I make it so more then one ID gets checked based on that value?

Comment: Yep! Exactly.  I updated the fiddle to show that. (slightly different syntax on the selector)

Comment: How can I do it with multiple checkbox IDs?

Comment: Weird, I typed it out like you had it and it was not working... I then just copied from fiddle and it worked!!! I checked like 5 times and I didn't see anything I left out. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're asking for. Hope it helps!

```js
function setCheckBox(value){
    var chk = document.getElementById('check1');
    chk.checked = (value != 'null');
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"/>Test 1:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="process1" onchange="setCheckBox(this.value);">
                <option value="null">--Select Option--</option>
                <option value="OptionA">Option A</option>
                <option value="OptionB">Option B</option>
                <option value="OptionB">Option C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your specifics, but this does what you asked and you should be able to take parts from it to complete your task.

```js
document.getElementById('changer').onchange = function(){
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++)
  {
   boxes[i].checked = boxes[i].id == this.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<select id='changer'>
  <option>None</option>
  <option value='a'>A</option>
  <option value='b'>B</option>
  <option value='c'>C</option>
  <option value='d'>D</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id='a' /><label for='a'>A</label><br />
<input type='checkbox' id='b' /><label for='a'>B</label><br />
<input type='checkbox' id='c' /><label for='a'>C</label><br />
<input type='checkbox' id='d' /><label for='a'>D</label>
```